# Como enviar un link por AJAX?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

lo que necesito específicamente es que al clickear un `<div>` o la etiqueta que fuese, actúe como un link, pero solo para pedir una petición JSON, es decir es un link que no dirige a ningún lado en especifico, solo realiza una tarea de escritura en el servidor. Por lo que necesito usar AJAX con una función `click()` que de alguna manera actúe por debajo como una etiqueta `<a>` pero no he encontrado como hacerlo. A continuación dejo un ejemplo mínimo del "corazón" que deseo clickear.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(this).find(".img-hover").mouseenter(function(){
  
    $(this).css({"background-color": "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)"});
    $(this).find("i").css({"color": "rgb(27, 27, 28)"});
    $(this).find("i").stop().removeClass("fa-2x");
    $(this).find("i").stop().addClass("fa-4x");
    $(this).find("span").stop().fadeIn(200);
  
  });
  
  $(this).find(".img-hover").mouseleave(function(){
  
    $(this).css({"background-color": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"});
    $(this).find("i").css({"color": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"});
    $(this).find("i").stop().removeClass("fa-4x");
    $(this).find("i").stop().addClass("fa-2x");
    $(this).find("span").stop().fadeOut(200);
  
  });
  
  $(this).find(".fa-heart").mouseenter(function(){
  
    $(this).css({"color": "rgb(234, 96, 86)"});
    
  });
  
  $(this).find(".fa-heart").mouseleave(function(){
  
    $(this).css({"color": "rgb(27, 27, 28)"});
    
  });

});
```

```css
*{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 font-family: sans-serif;
}

.contenedor {
 position: relative;
 width: 250px;
 height: 450px;
}

img {
 max-width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
}

.img-hover {
 width: 100%;
 height: 99%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 100;
 transition: .2s;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
 text-align: center;
}

.fa-heart {
 color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
 position: absolute;
 top: 40%;
 left: 40%;
 transition: .2s;
}

.fa-heart:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
}

.cuenta {
 padding: 3px 8px;
 background-color: rgb(247, 247, 247);
 border-radius: 3px;
 color: rgb(27, 27, 28);
 font-size: 12px;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 margin-right: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 6px;
 position: absolute;
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/acad8e21f9.js"></script>
<div class="contenedor">
  <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/0f/61/18/0f6118f167ccca50dff9e06f5b27146b.jpg" alt="img">
  <div class="img-hover">
    <!--Este es el "div" del click-->
    <i class="fa fa-heart fa-2x"></i>
    <!--Este es el "span" del resultado-->
    <span class="cuenta">716</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A ver si entiendo. Quieres enviar por ajax «un link» cuando ejecutes el corazón. ¿Qué link es este? ¿Lo generas?

Comment: Si, un link aleatorio de un plugin para Kirby.

Comment: Te recomiendo encodear el link con `encodeURIComponent` ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo visto ya trabajas con [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) pero no sé si con [AJAX de jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) así que te dejo la documentación por si acaso.

Respecto a la pregunta, debería bastar con un código así:

```
$(".img-hover").on("click", function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Direccion/de/la/accion",
        data: {
                  dato: "lo que envíes"
              }
        type: "POST",
        /*
         * Todo lo demás que quieras que suceda
         * con ese AJAX
         */
    });
});
```

Así, con cada click sobre un elemento (`div`, enlace, lo que sea) que tenga la clase `.img-hover` debería realizar la acción.

También puedes poner una clase propia y cambiar el `$(".img-hover")` por `$(".tu-clase")` para que sea más específico.

Comment: Gracias lo entiendo, pero la idea es simplemente ejecutar el enlace sin enviar ningún dato extra!

Comment: Claro, con AJAX puedes o no mandar lo que quieras!